# Local Variable usage reasoning

Tags: javascript

I have lot enough functions, which look like:

```
var functionName = function(e) {
  // 
};
```

where all the parameters are getting passed in in a single container `e`. Most times values are simple values (no functions), ex.:

```
{ parameter1: 1, parameter2: "Name", parameter3:{ subParameter1: "A"}}
```

But there're times when I pass in functions as in: `{ p2:function(){...} }`

I have two options when it comes to utilising parameter values:

Options 1: get parameter values from the chain, starting from `e`: e.parameter1, e.parameter3.subParameter1 etc.

Option 2: use cached parameter values:

```
var parameter1 = e.parameter1;
var subParameter1 = e.parameter3.subParameter1;
```

The second option improves readability but increases the number of vars and the size of the code base. On another hand it's much drier when using long chains, i.e. `e.p1.p2.p3` etc.

What reasoning should I use for choosing between those two options?

```
**Update 1 - the question sounds quite subjective, let me re-prase it.**
```

I don't mind using chains all the way, no local vars codebase is smaller, I can always figure out what's what, are the any cases when caching is a must?

Comment: `second option improves readability` if you feel that there are no other drawbacks, you already know what you prefer. This is a subjective question and will not get you definitive answers.

Comment: let me rephrase it - if I use e.parameter1 10 times through the function body, should I cache it into a local var or e.parameter1 is still okay?

Comment: If you worry about performance and you find yourself repeatedly accessing a (nested) property, store it in a variable. This is more important for older browsers, newer browsers seem to be better at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination, based on depth(`e.p1` vs `e.p1.sp2.ssp3`) and frequency of use.  Deeper sub-properties and high usage of any sub-property both benefit from caching.

Nested property look ups can get costly, and caching the value after executing the look up once is valuable if you're going to use it a lot.  This is only more efficient if you're accessing a particular property on the chain more than once, and the more you access it, the more you benefit from caching.

If you only have one level deep(`e.p1, e.p2, e.p3`) and you're only looking up each property value once, don't bother.

If you're accessing `e.p1.sp2.ssp3` all throughout your function, cache it for sure.